# Active Admin Filepicker.io error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, filepicker.io

I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails

I have `config.filepicker_rails.api_key = "MyApiKey"` in config/application.rb and the filepicker.io script is being called via `<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>` in my application layout.

I have this in my admin/geography.rb file:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Town" do
    f.input :town
    f.input :name
    f.filepicker_field :filepicker_url
  end
  f.actions
end
```

The error I am getting on my admin page is:

```
RuntimeError in Admin::Geographies#new

Showing /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@Guides/bundler/gems/active_admin-72a9c30cef47/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb where line #1 raised:

Set config.filepicker_rails.api_key

Extracted source (around line #1):
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
```

Has anyone experienced this or have a solution? I have tried moving it to my initializers/active_admin.rb file as well with no luck and I'm not sure where else to look for a remedy. There doesn't seem to be much info on a RoR Filepicker.io implementation outside of the github doc.

Comment: Can you show what was raised?

Comment: @polmiro Do you mean the error? It was the `Set config.filepicker_rails.api_key`

Comment: Did you ever get the `f.filepicker_field :filepicker_url` code to work in ActiveAdmin?  In my active admin form, that field doesn't show.

Comment: @RTIndy I didn't. I actually needed to use a WYSIWYG so I purchased Redactor which allows me to upload images as well.

Answer (score 0):

The version of filepicker-rails on rubygems doesn't support Rails4 at the moment (working on updating it). [The version on github should work so please grab it from there.](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails/)

(For more information, see: https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails/issues/55)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with the demo at https://github.com/maxtilford/filepicker-rails-demo. 
After hard coding the config.filepicker_rails.api_key in the application.rb instead of using ENV it worked.